# LEFT JOIN ISNULL

Tags: sql, left-join, isnull

trying to clean up a mess in a couple databases from a few years of bad decisions.  Using my example below, we have a field from 'X' that links to a field from 'Y'.  Problem is that 'X' was also used to link to a legacy system and holds a record for either system.  'Z' may contain an alternate link which i want to use IF the first connection is NULL...I'm lost of how to create this "efficiently" without running two separate queries into a temp table?  Thanks.

```
FROM dbo.x X
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT Y.id, Z.varnum 
        FROM dbo.y Y
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Z
        ON Y.id = Z.varnum) W
ON X.id = ISNULL(W.id,W.varnum)
```

Comment: To clarify, you first want to join X to Y and if it doesn't find a match, join X to Z?

Answer (score 2):

Use Coalesce function in select and two left joins

```
SELECT COALESCE(Y.ID, Z.VARNUM) FROM X
LEFT JOIN Y on X.ID = Y.ID
LEFT JOIN Z on X.ID = Z.VARNUM
```